# OS X Server 10.6 and Fully Qualified Domain Names

Tags: network, osx-server

From the [Advanced Server Admin for OS X Server v.10.6](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Advanced_Server_Admin_v10.6.pdf):

> You must have a fully qualified domain
>   name for each server’s IP addess in
>   the DNS system. The DNS zone must have
>   the reverse-lookup record for the name
>   and address pair. Not having a stable,
>   functioning DNS system with reverse
>   lookup leads to service failures and
>   unexpected behaviors.

I was recently bit by this requirement as my internal network doesn't have an internal DNS server. As a result, various applications and services ([User Management](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/User_Management_v10.6.pdf) in particular),  hosted on my XServe have experienced degraded performance. My question is, besides deploying my own DNS server ([dnsmasq](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) or [bind9](http://www.bind9.net/)) is there any other way to provide a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) for my X Serve?

**UPDATE**

Used the X Serve as its own DNS host, worked like a charm with very little configuration.

Comment: You can have Mac OS X Server run BIND9 itself (DNS service).

Comment: can i ask why you are resistant to running a DNS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only way to get a FQDN is by using a DNS server, either external to your Xserve or run on the Xserve itself. It's recommended with setting up Mac OS X to set up DNS first before anything else.